# Cumulocity : I can create a new role and its permission

Tags: cumulocity

Cumulocity : I can create a new role and its permission using Cumulocity UI Platform, I want to achieve same functionality using Cumulocity Rest API but I am not able find these rest APIs. Can anyone help me to achieve this ?

Comment: A quick look at API shows its not possible. If you really need this ( not sure why though) you can try to debug to see how this done ( what endpoint if any) is used in admin gui or you can write custom implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply trace what REST calls are done with the help of the Browser Developer Console. F12 for Chrome e.g.

By this you can track which REST calls are made when you use the UI. Basically the UI is only using REST calls itself. So everything what you can do in the UI can be done via REST API as well.

**Be aware:**
When there are undocumented REST APIs this might be related to the case, that these are subject to change in the future.